# Unable to connect to SFTP server using Filezilla

Tags: sftp, filezilla, macos-highsierra

I have installed FileZilla 3.41.2 on my macOS High Sierra 10.13.6. 
From the terminal if I do the following, I am able to connect to server and access the files the SFTP server

```
sftp my_user@my_server_ip
```

However when I connect to the same server using fileZilla I get the below error

```
Status:         Connecting to my_server_ip...
Response:       fzSftp started, protocol_version=8
Command:        open "my_user@my_server_ip" 22
Error:          Server unexpectedly closed network connection
Error:          Could not connect to server
```

In FileZilla's settings I have also increased my timeout to 30s and retry count to 1

Please can you help me figure out why I am unable to connect to the SFTP Server using Filezilla

Comment: Show us verbose logs for both `sftp` and FileZilla.

Comment: Does your `~/.ssh/config` or `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` (or whatever applies in macOS) specify any non-standard options that apply to `my_user@my_server_ip`? The point is these files affect `sftp` but FileZilla has its own config, I think.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem on one particular site.

Logging at the "verbose" level, as suggested above by @Martin revealed that there was a newline character at the end of the username that I'd pasted into the Site Manager window when setting up the Host details.

Removing the newline (and retyping the last few characters) resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It could perhaps be a problem with the default cipher used by FileZilla.
If you have access to the server you might find a logged error that looks something
like:

```
sshd[29972]: fatal: matching cipher is not supported: [cipher-name]
```

Unfortunately, FileZilla has no cipher option, so you cannot dictate the cipher.
The FileZilla Client doesn't use the `sftp` command, using instead a bundled one
(fzsftp). This executable is a modified version of PuTTY's psftp and cannot be
configured in any way.

You may try to match the OpenSSH version on the server with a FileZilla client
dating from the same period, but my knowledge about this is sketchy.